How to dismiss a bootstrap modal after a form is successfully filed?
I am learning HTML, CSS, JS and PHP and put on myself to make a page with lets the user leave a message, but i have not being able to implement a way to make the modal close after the user correctly submits the form.
here is the part of the CODE:
[...]
<div class="modal fade" id="messagebook" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Write a message:</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" onclick="clearForm()" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); save();">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" id="id">
                    <div class="book">
                      <label for="user">User:</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book">
                      <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br>
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <div class="book">
                      <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
                      <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="30" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" id="sub" class="but">Send</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <br>
[...]
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="SiteAjs.js"></script>
[...]

save() function JS CODE:
function save() {
    let id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let message= document.getElementById('message').value;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', id);
    formData.append('user', user);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('message', message);

    let action = id ? 'create' : 'create';

    fetch(`functions.php?action=${action}`, {method: 'POST', body: formData})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        loadData();
        clearForm();
    });
 }

this code was build based on one of the exercises from my college course.

You're so close - what did you try? What was the problem? You have some JS that runs to submit your form, that seems like the logical place to handle closing the modal, right?  So how to close a modal with JS?  Start with the docs - the table of JS methods describes a few which sound suitable, eg hide.  If you want to see more examples about how that works, a search for "bootstrap hide modal Javascript" turns up plenty of answers here on SO.

@Don'tPanic i have tried the examples on given on the bootstrap documentation and some of the examples i have seen online. i have tried the hide function a lot of times but it did not work, i am starting to wonder if its because my save() function is defined on "SiteA.js" and that is creating a problem.

Your question does not show any of those attempts, and you didn't describe them ... We can't help if you don't show us the problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

@Don'tPanic the first thing i tried was
<button type="submit" id="sub" class="but" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
but it did not work, then i tried to do something like put the hide() function inside of the the onsubmit= area after the save() function before i tried to add what was indicated on the bootstrap documentation to the point of putting the entire function inside the modal object inside my JS file, i do have the habit of deleting the code then it does not work so the part that is working goes back.

It looks like this line should be changed:
<button type="submit" id="sub" class="but">Send</button>

To this one:
<button type="submit" id="sub" class="but" data-bs-target="#messagebook" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Send</button>

Or hide the modal through JavaScript inside your save() function:
// Just for reference (can be outside the save function)...
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('messagebook'), {
  keyboard: false
});

// Should be inside your save function:
myModal.hide();

EDIT: Hmm... As you modal is defined through HTML, maybe the previous example is making things confusing... So, as it is not working in the specific case, try this approach instead:
const myModalElement = document.getElementById('messagebook');
const myModalObject = bootstrap.modal.getInstance(myModalElement);

myModalObject.hide();

I've made a complete implementation through the save() function:
function save() {
    let id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let message= document.getElementById('message').value;
    
    // EDIT:
    let modalElement = document.getElementById('messagebook');
    let modalObject = bootstrap.modal.getInstance(modalElement);
    
    // If you don't want to wait for the fetch return...
    // modalObject.hide();
    
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', id);
    formData.append('user', user);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('message', message);

    let action = id ? 'create' : 'create';

    fetch(`functions.php?action=${action}`, {method: 'POST', body: formData})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        loadData();
        clearForm();
        
        // EDIT:
        // If you want to wait for the fetch return...
        modalObject.hide();
        
    });
}

PS.: I think the previous example was creating a new modal instead of using the existing one (that was create automatically through html).

the first one works kind of but it will dismiss even then the form is incomplete
and the JS method is not working.
if this helps i will add the save() function code to the post

I fixed my answer. Please, see if the last code can solve your problem now.

i tried the edited version and now the function is not working giving me this:
Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap.modal is undefined     save http://localhost/SiteA/SiteAjs.js:50     onsubmit http://localhost/SiteA/Signbook.html:1
